# Module Pattern Error in ES6 (Augmentation)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm getting an error while using module pattern (Augmentation) with ES6 let keyword.

This works.

```
var Example = ( Example => {
    Example.name = "";
    return Example;
})( Example || {} );

console.log(Example);
```

This does not.

```
let Example = ( Example => {
    Example.name = "";
    return Example;
})( Example || {} );

console.log(Example);
```

**I'm getting this error.**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Example is not defined

```
})( Example || {} );
    ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer becomes fairly clear when you realize that this:

```
var x = (j => j)(x)
```

..becomes this:

```
var x = undefined
x = (j => j)(x)
```

It really declares `x` as `undefined` *before* evaluating the expression and setting `x` to the result.

However, `let` doesn't have that property - it's not hoisted:

```
let y = (j => j)(y)
```

..gets evaluated as just that.

`y` doesn't exist when you do `(j => j)(y)`, so it throws a reference error.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a bunch @towerofnix :)

Answer (score 1):

`var` declarations are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), meaning that the name is considered "declared", but `undefined` until assigned within the entire function scope (as opposed to block scope). On the contrary, ES6 `let` declarations are not hoisted, so referencing `Example` causes the `ReferenceError` since it has not been declared yet.